# Arkham Horror Put a Clue Token on this card?

Tags: arkham-horror

I can't seem to quite figure out how cards like [Amanda Sharpe's Pass/Fail](http://www.arkhamhorrorwiki.com/File%3APsAmandaSharpeFront.png) work where it states:

> ...put a Clue token on this Card

Do these clue tokens become usable as a bank of clue tokens, such as when sealing a gate?  Do you get to use them once the condition has passed or failed, and they are put into your normal clue token pool?  Or are these simply markers, unusable and lost when passed/failed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They're just markers; effectively you have to draw three unique items to pass her story.

Rules-wise, there's nothing that explicitly says this, it's just that the tokens are on the card, not in your possession, and there's nothing that says you can ever gain them or use them. I wouldn't say they're "lost" when passed/failed; you never actually had them as clue tokens. They just go back to the supply once the card doesn't need them, their purpose served.

A lot of cards in Arkham Horror use tokens of various kinds as markers. Many of the rumors use clue tokens to keep track of "how bad is it" (for example [The Great Ritual](http://www.arkhamhorrorwiki.com/The_Great_Ritual)). When possible, they'll use an appropriate type of token for the function of the card, like the [Golden Trumpet](http://www.arkhamhorrorwiki.com/Golden_Trumpet) which prevents sanity loss and uses sanity tokens to track it. But most things don't have an obvious choice like that, so clue tokens are a nice generic choice that you're unlikely to be out of.

Comment: Agreed.  In the cases where the tokens types don't matter, you could use anything (number on the dice, coins, other game tokens).  I can't think of any examples where the token types do matter.  Even for the Golden Trumpet example if you used stamina tokens (example), it'd still prevent sanity loss.  There have definitely been cases where I've been out of the tokens requested so used something else.

Comment: Even when they don't actually matter in terms of rules/mechanics, they still matter in the sense that they help remind you what you're doing. If you used stamina tokens on Golden Trumpet you might be pretty prone to accidentally using it to prevent stamina loss.

Comment: *nods* I wasn't trying to say "confuse yourself", I was trying to say "If you're out of sanity tokens don't stress"=)  Sorry.